How to debug Julia script in VS studio code using a different project/environment
I have a Julia script named by xx.jl, and I set the package and modules in another directory ../my_env. So every time I want to run it, I used the command in the terminal Julia --project=../my_env ./xx.jl. However, if I used the debug mode of VS studio, it always activate the environment/project under the current directory (where I didn't install the package or module). So what can I do? I tried to modify the launch.json as following:
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "julia",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Run active Julia file",
            "program": "${file}",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "env": {},
            // "juliaEnv": "${command:activeJuliaEnvironment}"
            "juliaEnv": "/Users/xshan/Research/MPI/XXXX/examples/my_env"
        }
    ]
}

But it doesn't work...(Besides I am on Mac...
